# The background picture does not appear on my site

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-8

My background does not appear on my site :

```
.bg-dispersed {
    background-image: url("/images/jpg/bg_dispersed.jpg");
}
.bg-00 {
    background-image: url("/images/jpg/bg_home.jpg");
}
```

what is strange is that locally, it works.

Here is the URL of my site : https://overlap.ulb.be/public/

I have no error in the Firefox console.

I have this in my .env file :

```
ASSET_URL=https://overlap.ulb.be/public
```

The picture is inside the folder...

Comment: If you open up your browser's developer console and check both the Console and Network tabs, you'll see it's trying to access https://overlap.ulb.be/images/jpg/bg_home.jpg, not https://overlap.ulb.be/public/images/jpg/bg_home.jpg. You need to add `public` to the links

Comment: the problem is with your url put ../ before images

Comment: You should fix the bigger issue, change your vhost root folder to /public like `DocumentRoot "/www/projectName/public"` and those urls will get in place by themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css you have:
`background-image: url("images/jpg/bg_home.jpg");`

But you need

`background-image: url("../images/jpg/bg_home.jpg");`

The path in style.css is relative to the css folder, not to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

- background-image:url({{asset('/images/jpg/bg_dispersed.jpg')}});
- try to get 777 permission to storage/public folder
- assign height and width to class bg-dispersed and bg-00

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).